# Purpose of “lui” in “Et lui aussi il est bilingue ?”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I am reading a book in which there is the following question:

> Et lui aussi il est bilingue ?

I don't understand the usage of "lui" here though. I wonder how the following question is different:

> Et aussi il est bilingue ?

Or

> Et il aussi est bilingue ?

Comment: I suppose the nearest translation would be "And that guy, is he bilingual too?" though indeed in English, I feel it would be heavy and the most natural way would simply be "Is he bilingual too?" (the too referring to another person, not to another quality of "he").

Comment: @Chop That makes sense. As far as I've understood too, French speakers tend to ask questions in a longer manner compared to the equivalent questions in English. For example, "Where do you study?" is asked this way in French: "Where is it that you study?" (Où est-ce que tu étudies ?)

Comment: In casual spoken French, there can be even longer variants, e.g. *C'est où, là où tu étudie ?*, *Où c'est que c'est, [la] où tu étudie ?* or that shorter one *T'étudie où ?*. The "educated" way should have been "Où étudie-tu ?".

Comment: The last proposal is not French at all. You cannot insert an adverb between the subject *il* and its conjugated verb.

Comment: @jlliagre To me, it's interesting and really strange that the the casual spoken French is usually longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first question is spoken French duplicating the third person pronoun.
It might have been written :

> Et lui aussi est bilingue ?

i.e.

> (Someone is already bilingual,) is he (another guy) bilingual too ?

Your first alternative would need a comma:

> Et aussi, il est bilingue ?

and has a different meaning :

> And among other things, is he bilingual?

The second one should be reordered:

> Et il est aussi bilingue ?

Here, the question is less precise and its meaning can be either of the previous ones, depending on the context.